# got "No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform' " when try to import TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed the latest anaconda navigator 1.9.7 (windows 10), and created a new env (python 3.7)in the anaconda navigator interface, then installed jupyter notebook and tensorflow 2.0 package in it.

when I tried to import tensorflow as follow

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     23 import traceback
     24 
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
     26 
     27 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform'
```

i tried use

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

and
redid it inside that directory

nothing worked so far.

any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try it with 3 < python version < 3.6 ? Try with 3.6.

Comment: 3.6 works, but I need to pip uninstall and reinstall tensorflow. I don't know the reason of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone from git ,you can

> just change the folder from the one where you run the configure/bazel and then try python import tensorflow as tf